# jconsole (Java 7) on Linux cannot attach to a JVM process but jconsole (Java 6) can

Tags: java, java-7, jmx, java-6, jconsole

When I launch JConsole (version 1.7.0_80-b15) the different local JVM PIDs are displayed but JConsole only can attach to several ones, not to all of them (greyed out).

When I click on an attachable PID, the message **`Note: The management agent will be enabled on this process`** is displayed at the bottom of the PID list. When I click on an unattachable PID, the shown message is **`Note: The management agent is not enabled on this process`**.

The unattachable JVM process is version 1.7.0_80-b15 and has the following properties as command-line arguments:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6002
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

But if I launch the Jconsole (1.6.0_24-b07), that same "unattachable" PID is **not greyed out** (no **Note** is shown at the bottom of the PID list, though) and Jconsole has no problem to attach to it.

Why does JConsole v6 run and does JConsole v7 not?

Comment: jconsole is patch version specific. If it is newer than your JVM, it might not connect to an older version but an older version of jconsole might.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, why?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, both JConsole and running unattachable JVM process are version **1.7.0_80-b15**

Comment: In that case, I don't know.